# SyntaxError in Cython

Tags: python-3.x, runtime-error, cython, cythonize

The code was working well, but out of nowhere it started giving Syntax Error, which appears to be incorrect. The code compiled well, and the error is only during run time.How to debug it? Code :-

```
cdef void connect():
    print("Hello")

connect()
```

and the error is: - 
cdef void connect():
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: This sounds like the compiled module isn't on the path so you're importing the uncompiled code and trying to interpret it in Python instead. Since your source file is Cython and not Python you should give it a .pyx extension

Answer (score 0):

The error was because i was running the program instead of importing it.